# what is wrong with this code public class Hello { public static void main() { System.out.println("Doesn't execute");

Tags: java, eclipse

I typed this code  into Eclipse

```
 public class Hello 
 {
   public static void main() 
   {
      System.out.println("Doesn't execute");
   }
   // .....
 }
```

When I press run it says that it does not contain a main type.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong , and I am new to java.

Comment: Did any of the solutions help? Please select an answer.

Answer (score 6):

It should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 5):

This is what your code should look like:

```
public class Hello {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Doesn't execute");
   }
}
```

Notice the closing parenthesis, also I have properly changed your main method.

Here's another hint:
When you create a new Java class in Eclipse, there is an option to auto-generate the main method stub for you (this option would have fixed your error without you even knowing).

It is the first checked checkbox in the following screenshot.
[image: Add main method stub is checked]

Comment: eclipse also has auto-complete macros for stuff like this. For instance, if you type `main` and then press ctrl+space it will create a main method.

Answer (score 0):

main method without the string array arguments is not the method that JVM looks for to start the execution of a class.

After completion of the initialization for a class (during which other consequential loading, linking, and initializing may have occurred), the method main of class is invoked.

**The method main must be declared public, static, and void**. **It must specify a formal parameter whose declared type is array of String**. Therefore, either of the following declarations is acceptable:

```
public static void main(String[] args)

public static void main(String... args)
```

Read more about JVM startup, loading, linking and intilization of class here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4